# unable to dispacth a action to the store in redux

Tags: redux, next.js

in checkOut js im unable to access the data inside the items arrey but i can access the length how is it possible i added 3 items i can see the items.lenth but when try to use items.map its not working showing error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')

store.ts

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import basketReducer from "./basketSlice";

//this is redux like a global store to store users items data 
//when users put the items in the shopping cart
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    basket: basketReducer,
  },
});
```

busketSlice.ts

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

interface BasketItem {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  image: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  category: string;
}

const initialState = {
  items: [] as BasketItem[],
};

export const basketSlice = createSlice({
  name: "basket",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToBasket: (state, action) => {
      state.items = state.items.concat(action.payload);
    },
    removeFromBasket: (state, action) => {
      const index = state.items.findIndex((basketItem: any) => basketItem.id === action.payload.id)
    
      let newBasket = [...state.items];

      if (index >= 0){
        //if item exists in the basket remove it ...
        newBasket.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        console.warn(`cant remove (id: ${action.payload.id}) because its not in busket`)
      }

      state.items = newBasket;
    },
  },
});

export const { addToBasket, removeFromBasket } = basketSlice.actions;

// Selectors - This is how we pull information from the Global store slice
export const selectItems = (state: any) => state.basket.items;
export const selectTotal = (state: any) => state.busket.items.reduce((total:any, item:any) => total + item.price, 0);
 const basketReducer = basketSlice.reducer;
 export default basketReducer;
```

Cards.tsx

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StarIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid';
// import Currency from 'react-currency-formatter';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { addToBasket } from "../basketSlice"

export default function Cards({id,title,image,description,price,category}: any) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const addItemsToBusket = () => {
    const product = {
      id,title,image,description,price,category
    }
    dispatch(addToBasket(product))//sending the product as an action to the redux store
  }
  
  const [rating, set] = useState(5);
  const [hasPrime, setH] = useState(Math.random() < 1)
 
  useEffect(() => {
    set(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1 );
   }, [])

   useEffect(() => {
    setH(Math.random() < 0.5 );
   }, [])

  return (
    <div className="relative z-30 flex flex-col p-10 m-5 bg-white ">
        <p className='absolute text-xs italic right-2 top-2'>{category}</p>
        <Image className='mx-auto' src={image} height={200} width={200} alt=""/>

        <h4 className='my-3'>{title}</h4>

        <div className='flex'>
          {Array(rating).fill(rating).map((_, i) => (
            <StarIcon key={i} className='h-6 text-yellow-500'/>
          ))}
        </div> 
       
        <p className='my-2 text-xs line-clamp-2 '>{description}</p>

        <div>
          {/* <Currency quantity={props.price} currency="INR"/> */}
          <p className='mb-5'>₹{price}</p>
        </div>

        {hasPrime && (
          <div className='flex items-center -mt-5 space-x-2'>
            <img 
             className='w-12'
            src="https://links.papareact.com/fdw" alt="" />
            <p className='text-xs text-gray-500'>Free Next-Day Delivary</p>
          </div>
        )}

        <button onClick={addItemsToBusket} className='mt-auto button'>Add to Busket</button>

    </div>
  )
}
```

ProductsFeed.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Cards from './Cards'

export default function({ products }: any) {
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-flow-row-dense mx-auto md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 md:-mt-40 lg:-mt-52">
       {products.slice(0,4).map((product: any) => (
        <Cards
          key={product.id}
          id={product.id}
          title={product.title}
          price={product.price * 60}
          description={product.description}
          category={product.category}
          image={product.image}
        />
       ))}
       <img className="md:col-span-full" src="https://links.papareact.com/dyz" alt="" />
       <div className='md:col-span-2'>
        {products.slice(4,5).map((product: any) => (
         <Cards
          key={product.id}
          id={product.id}
          title={product.title}
          price={product.price * 60}
          description={product.description}
          category={product.category}
          image={product.image}
         />
        ))}
        </div>
        {products.slice(5, products.length).map((product: any) => (
         <Cards
          key={product.id}
          id={product.id}
          title={product.title}
          price={product.price * 60}
          description={product.description}
          category={product.category}
          image={product.image}
         />
        ))}
       
    </div>
  )
}
```

checkout.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Nav from '../components/Nav'
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react"
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectItems } from '../basketSlice';
import CheckOutProduct from '../components/CheckOutProduct';




export default function CheckOut() {

  const { data: session } = useSession()
  const items = useSelector(selectItems);
  console.warn(items)
  return (
    <div className='h-screen bg-gray-100'>
        <Nav />
        <main>
            {!session?  (
              <div>
                <div className='flex items-center justify-start p-10 m-10 space-x-4 overflow-hidden bg-white md:space-x-10'>
                  <img src="/checkout.svg" className='h-[7rem] w-[7rem]  sm:w-[15rem] sm:h-[15rem]'   alt=""/>
                 <div className=''>
                  <h1 className='font-bold md:text-[2rem] mb-1'>Your Amazon Cart is empty</h1>
                  <p className='text-[#007185] hover:text-red-600 cursor-pointer hover:underline hover'>Shop today's deals</p>
                  <button 
                   className='px-10 py-2 mt-4 button'
                   onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in to your account</button>
                 </div>
                </div>
                <div className=' h-[5rem] bg-white mx-10' />
              </div>
            ): (
              <div>
                <div className='flex items-center justify-start p-10 m-10 space-x-4 overflow-hidden bg-white md:space-x-10'>
                  <img src="/checkout.svg" className='h-[7rem] w-[7rem]  sm:w-[15rem] sm:h-[15rem]'   alt=""/>
                 <div className=''>
                  <h1 className='font-bold md:text-[2rem] mb-1'>
                    {items.length === 0? "Your Amazon Cart is empty": "Shoping Basket"}
                  </h1>
                  <p className='text-[#007185] hover:text-red-600 cursor-pointer hover:underline hover'>Shop today's deals</p>

                 </div>
                </div>
                <div className='mx-10 bg-white '>
                  {items.length !== 0 && `You have ${items.length} items in your busket.`}
                  {items.map(({item, i}: any) => {
                    <CheckOutProduct 
                      key={i}
                      image={item.image}
                      price={item.price}/>
                  })} 
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
        </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

checkOutProduct.tsx

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import React from 'react'

export default function CheckOutProduct({ id,title,image,description,price,category }: any) {
  return (
    <div className='grid grid-cols-5'>
       <Image src={image} height={200} width={200} alt=""/>
       <p>{price}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add like below because concat will not change object reference since updated values will not show in component.

```
 addToBasket: (state, action) => {
      state.items = [...state.items, ...action.payload];
 }
```

Comment: wrong 
TypeError: action.payload is not iterable

Comment: before I tried  this didn't work as well

 state.items = [...state.items, action.payload]

Comment: i fixed the issue i was having a type error

Comment: Ok cool great ….